# Read dictionary from file into original lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, dictionary, load

I have one nested list, and one list for "numbers"

```
 test_keys = [["tobbe", "kalle"],["karl", "Clara"],["tobbe"],["tank"]]
 test_values = ['123', '234','345','456']

 res = {}
 for key in test_keys:
     for value in test_values:
         res[value] = key
         test_values.remove(value)
         break

 with open("myfile.txt", 'w') as f: 
     for key, value in res.items(): 
         f.write('%s;%s;\n' % (key, value))
```

This provides the file

```
123;['tobbe', 'kalle'];
234;['karl', 'Clara'];
345;['finis'];
456;['tank'];
```

now I want to load the data back into the a dictionary without the ";" and later on back into the corresponding lists.

Comment: Your example file doesnt match your example code

Comment: If you want to read/write a dict from a file, use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json).

Comment: This tutorial has everything you need to learn this the right way.  Any tree-like data structure ... you should be thinking `json` for serialization (putting in file): https://realpython.com/python-json/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
res = {}

with open("myfile.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        chunks = line.split(';')
        names = chunks[1][1:-1].split(', ')
        res[chunks[0]] = [name[1:-1] for name in names]

print(res)

test_keys = []
test_values = []

for key in res:
    test_keys.append(key)
    test_values.append(res[key])


print(test_keys)
print(test_values)
```

Comment: Yes! indeed, thank you so much was really stuck! omg you just saved me! I will try to understand the code now!

Comment: No problem! Basically I just went through the file line by line, split each line into chunks by semi-colon, removed the square brackets from the values chunk, split that chunk into individual values by comma (and a trailing space), removed single quotes for each value, then stored all the values in a list, and lastly inserting the list into the dictionary!

Comment: You are a lifesaver, Trying to learn, but it's hard!